# "GORM support for Hadoop HBase plugin" is not supporting for grails 2.1.0

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hbase, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

When I install Grails plugin "GORM support for Hadoop HBase". I am getting this error.

> | Error Plugin gorm-hbase-0.2.4 requires version [1.3.2] of Grails
>   which your cu rrent Grails installation does not meet. Please try
>   install a different version of the plugin or Grails.

How can I overcome this without back-stepping to older version of grails Or anyother alternate plugin is available in grails to access hbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin is only compatible with Grails up to 1.3.2, I'm not sure about what you can do...

It doesn't look like there are other hbase plugins available but the one that you mentioned, so basically you have 2 choices:

- You can either fix the code yourself, not sure if you can or are willing to do it.
- You could ask the maintainer of that plugin if it's easy to port the code to the latest Grails version.

Comment: I did't do either because it is bit time-taking and this plugin is doing some auto-generated stuff which is hard to customize.So, I went-off individually to do everything on my own. Anyhow, Thanks for ur suggestion.